# Fractal dimension algorithms gives results of >2 for time-series

Tags: arrays, algorithm, python-3.x

I'm trying to compute Fractal Dimension of very specific time series array.

I've found implementations of Higuchi FD algorithm:

```
def hFD(a, k_max): #Higuchi FD

L = []
x = []
N = len(a)

for k in range(1,k_max):
    Lk = 0
    for m in range(0,k):
        #we pregenerate all idxs
        idxs = np.arange(1,int(np.floor((N-m)/k)),dtype=np.int32)
        Lmk = np.sum(np.abs(a[m+idxs*k] - a[m+k*(idxs-1)]))
        Lmk = (Lmk*(N - 1)/(((N - m)/ k)* k)) / k
        Lk += Lmk

    L.append(np.log(Lk/(m+1)))
    x.append([np.log(1.0/ k), 1])

(p, r1, r2, s)=np.linalg.lstsq(x, L)
return p[0]
```

from https://github.com/gilestrolab/pyrem/blob/master/src/pyrem/univariate.py

and Katz FD algorithm:

```
def katz(data):

n = len(data)-1
L = np.hypot(np.diff(data), 1).sum() # Sum of distances
d = np.hypot(data - data[0], np.arange(len(data))).max() # furthest distance from first point
return np.log10(n) / (np.log10(d/L) + np.log10(n))
```

from https://github.com/ProjectBrain/brainbits/blob/master/katz.py

I expect results of ~1,5 in both cases however get 2,2 and 4 instead...

hFD(x,4) = 2.23965648024 (k value of here is chosen as an example, however result won't change much in range 4-12 edit: I was able to get result of ~1,9 with k=22, however this still does not make any sense);

katz(x) = 4.03911343057

Which in theory should not be possible for 1D time-series array.

Questions here are: are Higuchi and Katz algorithms not suitable for time-series analysis in general, or am I doing something wrong on my side? Also are there any other python libraries with already implemented and error-less algorithms to verify my results?

My array of interest (each element represents point in time t, t+1, t+2,..., t+N)

```
    x = np.array([373.4413096546802, 418.58026161917803,
          395.7387698762124, 416.21163042783206,
          407.9812265426947, 430.2355284504048,
          389.66095393296763, 442.18969320408166,
          383.7448638776275, 452.8931822090381,
          413.5696828065546, 434.45932712853585
          ,429.95212301648996, 436.67612861616215,
          431.10235365546964, 418.86935850068545,
          410.84902747247423, 444.4188867775925,
          397.1576881118471, 451.6129904245434,
          440.9181246439599, 438.9857353268666,
          437.1800408012741, 460.6251405281339,
          404.3208481355302, 500.0432305427639,
          380.49579242696177, 467.72953450552893,
          333.11328535523967, 444.1171938340972,
          303.3024198243042, 453.16332062153276,
          356.9697406524534, 520.0720647379901,
          402.7949987727925, 536.0721418821788,
          448.21609036718445, 521.9137447208354,
          470.5822486372967, 534.0572029633416,
          480.03741443274765, 549.2104258193126,
          460.0853321729541, 561.2705350421926,
          444.52689144575794, 560.0835589548401,
          462.2154563472787, 559.7166600213686,
          453.42374550322353, 559.0591804941763,
          421.4899935529862, 540.7970410737004,
          454.34364779193913, 531.6018122709779,
          437.1545739076901, 522.4262260216169,
          444.6017030695873, 533.3991716674865,
          458.3492761150962, 513.1735160522104])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array you are trying to estimate hDF is too short. You need to get longer sample or oversample the current one to have at least 128 points for hDF and more then 4000 points for Katz

```
import scipy.signal as signal
```

...

```
x_res=signal.resample(x,128)
```

hfd(x_res,4) will be 1.74383694265

Comment: Thanks! Can you also point to a source where you found numbers 128 and 4000? Also - doesn't oversampling slightly reduces actuall FD?